# restrict shell commands for munin-node (netcat)

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, munin

I've spent fair amount of day fiddling with this, and I'm about to give up (for today).

I followed the instructions outlined [here](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/Native_ssh).

All works at the moment. But to increase security I'd like to implement some limits in authorized_keys file.

I tried:

```
command="/bin/nc",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty
ssh-dss AAAAB3....o9M9qz4xqGCqGXoJw= user@host
```

Since tutorial uses this command on munin-nodes:

```
address ssh://floppa.example.com/bin/nc localhost 4949
```

I thought munin only would need that to run smoothly. But I was wrong. Restricting shell only to /bin/nc causes timeout error on munin-master.

How do I implement this limit and not break the way munin native ssh works?

Comment: What is your version of munin master ? What is the result of "ssh floppa.example.com /bin/nc localhost 4949". They use /usr/bin/nc, is it ok for you to use /bin/nc ?

Comment: @kranteg I use Munin version 2.0.19. ssh floppa.example.com /bin/nc localhost 4949 returns remote server shell, whre I can type list and get plugin data from munin-node. I'm on debian netcat resides in /bin/nc

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
command="/bin/nc localhost 4949",no-pty,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding
```